# What is a single word or idiom for overcoming a trying situation?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

Recently, my friend's office was burned due to a shortcircuit in a switchboard. So, I want to give them some positive message. E.g. –

> Must be a trying situation for you guys. Take care guys! I hope you ___ this situation.

I want to use some idiom or a word. Closest I found is **overcome**, but I don't feel like using it.

Comment: What is wrong with *overcome* that you don't want to use it? Without knowing what kind of word you're looking for, we would just be guessing.

Comment: @JasonBassford I always use the word overcome. So, I want different word or idiom to express same thought.

Comment: The single word that I believe is the closest in meaning to *overcome* is [***surmount***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surmount). However, I can't provide that as an answer, because it would sound strange if put into your sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend

***TO COPE WITH***.

According to [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cope) :

***cope***

intransitive verb

1a: to deal with and attempt to overcome problems and difficulties —
 often used with *with*

//  to cope with the demands of her schedule

Comment: I'll wait for few more suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You might try **[get through](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/get-through)** or **[come through](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/come-through)** with an adverb at the end to emphasize how you want them to get through it. Both phrasal verbs imply dealing with a difficult situation.

"I hope you get through this situation [quickly/easily/alright/soon]."

Comment: +1 I would use use *get through* myself.

Answer (score 1):

A higher purpose of a mistake that harms us is learning, so in this particular case I will use the verb to learn, instead of to overcome. Overcoming not necessarily makes you grow from your mistakes, and learning is always the most positive outcome from an error. Therefore if I were you, I will tell to your friend:

I hope you will learn from this situation so it won't happen again.

Comment: I think that "I hope you will learn from this situation" could easily be taken as patronizing or condescending rather than supportive.

Comment: If you assume that OP's friend was culprit, then you are correct. But, I don't see that OP mentioned it anywhere in his/her description that the friend intentionally or playfully short-circuited the switchboard.